# Separate Wrap text to multiple rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell

i've an issue which is i couldnt seperate wrap text cell to multiple row in excel,

here is the example :-

Wrap Text :

[image: Wrap Text]
[image]

Without Wrap Text :

[image: Without wrap Text]
[image]

so now I want to separate the without wrap text to multiple rows, the details will be looks like in wrap text.

Comment: You mean you want to split the text on newline characters? Have a look at the  `TEXTSPLIT()` function or PowerQuery.

Comment: Yes, Power Query could be better here. Otherwise if you have access to MS365 then `REDUCE()` with `TEXTSPLIT()` i believe you will not have just one cell of data. Could you post few more samples.

Comment: I add one more example, the format is same, but when i untick the wrap text, it will become like that.

Comment: Try: =`TEXTSPLIT(H2,,CHAR(10))`

Comment: @sephiroth have you tried the above formula yet? or where are you facing problem in still

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I've tried and it's worked perfectly with the wrap text, may i know what is the explanation of the TEXTSPLIT(H2,,CHAR(10)) so that i can understand the formula?

Comment: @sephiroth just posted in answers, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=TEXTSPLIT(A1,,CHAR(10))
```

---

Where <kbd>CHAR( )</kbd> function returns a character specified by the code number from the character set for your computer, therefore in the above formula it splits by line break. <kbd>CHAR(10)</kbd>

---